# For a matrix A such that $Ax \ge 0$ has no non zero solution, find the closest matrix A' to A such that $A'x \ge 0$ has non zero solutions.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-rank

We know that for a matrix A where $Ax = 0$ has no non zero solution, the smallest eigenvalue of A represents the distance from A to the closest matrix A' such that $A'x = 0$ has non zero solutions. Is there an analogous measure for the problem described in the title?

Comment: Is $Ax\geq0$ to be understood componentwise?

Comment: yes, the inequality is componentwise.

Comment: It is impossible for a square matrix $A$ to be such that  $Ax \geq 0$ fails to have a non-zero solution. In order for the condition to apply, $A$ must be $m \times n$ with $m>n$ and linearly independent columns.

Comment: $m>n$ is the case that I am interested in. Could you also elaborate or provide a reference on how to understand / prove your statement?

Comment: In the problem I am looking at, linearly independent columns should also hold. Additionally, each row has a constant number of entries and each column is also sparse.

Comment: @twomushrooms if $A$ has linearly dependent columns, then $Ax = 0$ has a non-zero solution. If $A$ is square with independent columns, then we can take $x = A^{-1}b$ for some vector $b \geq 0$.